# a beautiful solution to decode a table with dplyr and mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Dear dplyr/tidyverse companions, I am looking for a nice solution to the following problem. I only get my solutions in base R with a loop. How do you solve this cleanly in tidyverse?

1. I have a dataset called data, which has not useful column names and not useful values (integer).

```
data <- tibble(var1 = rep(c(1:3), 2), 
               var2 = rep(c(1:3), 2))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   var1  var2
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     1     1
5     2     2
6     3     3
```

2. Additional I have a coding table, which has for every column a better name (var1 -> variable1) and a better value (1 -> "a")

```
coding <- tibble(variable = c(rep("var1", 3),rep("var2", 3)),
                     name = c(rep("variable1", 3),rep("variable2", 3)),
                     code = rep(c(1:3), 2),
                     value = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  variable name       code value
  <chr>    <chr>     <int> <chr>
1 var1     variable1     1 a    
2 var1     variable1     2 b    
3 var1     variable1     3 c    
4 var2     variable2     1 a    
5 var2     variable2     2 b    
6 var2     variable2     3 c
```

3. I'm looking for a result, which has transformed names of the columns and the real values as factors in the dataset, compare:

```
result <- tibble(variable1 = factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2)), 
                 variable2 = factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2)))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  variable1 variable2
  <fct>     <fct>    
1 a         a        
2 b         b        
3 c         c        
4 a         a        
5 b         b        
6 c         c
```

Thank you for your commitment :) :) :) :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, I am afraid that this post is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow is better suited for specific issues with your code. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  left_join(coding, by = c(ind = "variable", values = "code")) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(j = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = j, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-j)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   variable1 variable2
#   <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 a         a        
# 2 b         b        
# 3 c         c        
# 4 a         a        
# 5 b         b        
# 6 c         c
```

Answer (score 2):

A general solution for any number of columns -

- create a row number column to identify each row
- get `data` in long format
- join it with `coding` for each value
- keep only unique rows and get it back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_to = 'code')  %>%
  left_join(coding, by = 'code') %>%
  select(row, name = name.y, value) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  select(-row)

# variable1 variable2
#  <chr>     <chr>    
#1 a         a        
#2 b         b        
#3 c         c        
#4 a         a        
#5 b         b        
#6 c         c
```